# How many ways could Alice have filled out the answer sheet?

Tags: logical-deduction

Alice, Brie, Carlos, and Drake are taking a true/false quiz at school. There are four questions.
The teacher was sneaky and made the answer to every question "true." Each person got a
different score, with Alice scoring the highest.
How many ways could Alice have filled out the answer sheet?
NOTE: The answer sheet has an ordered sequence of true/false answers; for example, truetrue-
false-false on this test would score 50%. True-false-true-false and false-false-true-true
would also both score 50%; they are all considered different ways of filling out the answer
sheet.

Comment: Hi Pedram and welcome to Puzzling! This looks like a puzzle you found elsewhere. Please could you provide the original source of this question, as we have an anti-plagiarism policy which means we need to ensure any content is attributed to the correct creator. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is

> Five.

Reasoning:

> Since they all got different scores, Alice could only have got a perfect score, and the others scoring any three of 0%, 25%, 50% or 75%; or she could have missed at most one question, with the others scoring 0%, 25% and 50%. There is only one way to get a perfect score, and 4 possible ways to miss one question. 1 + 4 = 5.